# How do I make a Stream version of Future.wait in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to run `Future.wait()` on some network calls so they can run concurrently. I want to speed this up even further my returning the results as they become available  so I can start displaying them. I figured just a small modification to the `Future.wait` call would be all I need, but unfortunately, it uses private classes internally. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

[Future.wait dart documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Stream.fromFutures` [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromFutures.html)

> The stream reports the results of the futures on the stream in the
> order in which the futures complete. Each future provides either a
> data event or an error event, depending on how the future completes.
>
> If some futures have already completed when Stream.fromFutures is
> called, their results will be emitted in some unspecified order.
>
> When all futures have completed, the stream is closed.

```
Stream<int> streamingInts = Stream.fromFutures([
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 1),
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 2),
]);

 await for (final i in streamingInts) {
   print(i);   
 }
```

My real use case - to show that loading takes more time than expected

1. if my real api call ends fast I just yield LoadedState & stop listen to stream
2. if my real api call is too slow special Future.delayed will fire special state LoadingTakesTooLongState

```
      Stream<BlocState> loadingStates = Stream.fromFutures([
        Future.delayed(_kTooSlowDelay, () => LoadingTakesTooLongState()),
        _loadData(),
      ]);

      await for (var state in loadingStates) {
        yield state;
        if (state is LoadedState) break;
      }

      Future<LoadedState> _loadData() ...
```